# How can I make a script that automatically slices zipped files and mails them?

Tags: server, zip, rar

I have a site where I want to have a form in which people upload their zipped photos. Then I want my site to automatically send me emails of the zip sliced into 25mb files. This is so that the site doesn't host the files permanently.

Comment: Well intial upload and mailing isnt a problem. Its the slicing that has to be done. I have no idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Use 7zip instead. It's free and it's capable of making volumes with defined size.

```
7z a -v25M vol.7z sourcefiles
```

where **a** is for add and **-v25M** is volume size of 25MB.

This will create vol.7z.001, vol.7z.002, vol.7z.003 each having 25MB and the last file will hold the rest.